# Java licensing API

Tags: java, api, licensing, keystore

I just came across [TrueLicense Project](https://truelicense.dev.java.net/tutorial.html) API for licensing Java projects. I want to know are there any other similar APIs available? Please suggest me some.

Also I am not familiar with the process of generating the keystore which is needed for this. Can anyone guide me about the process of generating .store file which is used in this API?

Thanks.

Comment: found any good solution? I see jLicense too, but it's not much popular.

Comment: Finally got away with creating a custom API on this one.

Answer (score 1):

Following is the link where steps are provided to generate provate and public key stores using java keytool.
http://technologytriumph.blogspot.in/2012/10/steps-to-generate-public-priavet-key.html

Truelicense is a good option as per my view.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried jLicense and it worked fine for me. I tested the GUI which creates the license keys and then ran the test to test the license.

http://freecode.com/projects/jlicense

http://www.websina.com/products/jlicense.html